# NSTextField not contained by the NSView on resize

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, nstextview, autolayout

I have an NSTextView that I put on top of NSView. (NSView->NSTextView)

[image]

When I move the window around, the label stays put (in the middle of the view), but when I resize the view, the label goes away.

[image]

What's the right way to make sure the label ALWAYS stays centered where I put it?  I also tried putting it inside another custom NSView (NSView->NSView->NSTextField), but it doesn't stay centered.

For what it's worth I'm using auto layout in Xcode 4:

[image]

Comment: Centred horizontally or vertically?

Comment: What I want is for it to stay few pixels above the bottom edge (I already have it centered), but setting a constraint (as shown above) doesn't do it.

Comment: What are the constraints on the parent view itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by creating a bottom bar (content border=large bottom border setting in IB on the main window)

Answer (score 0):

Please mind that you can define the layout behavior of the subview (your label) by the **autoresizing settings** in the Size inspector of Interface Builder.

[image: Size inspector / Autoresizing settings]

1. Select the label.
2. Open the Size inspector.
3. Enable the red arrows as shown in the screenshot.